# Notation for translating vectors

Tags: geometry, notation, terminology

I'm completely new to vector geometry and recently encountered some new notation (and wholly unfamiliar) for the translation of vectors.

$$T:Z \mapsto A + Z$$

The above is described as

> A translation by vector $A$

Again, I have no idea why they call it a translation **by** vector $A$ and not **of** vector $A$. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding the whole thing.

Can somebody shed some light on the matter?

Comment: Do they say what is $Z$? Because for me, this would mean a translation that "brings $Z$ to $A$", i.e., a translation "by $A-Z$".

Comment: @tohecz: I'm sorry, I left out the $Z$ in the question. I edited it. They don't say what $Z$ is. They just say 'this function is a translation by $A$'.

Comment: Normally $Z$ would be a point, and $A$ a displacement (vector); the result $A+Z$ is another point. I personally prefer writing $Z+A$, with the displacement added to the point rather than the other way around, but it does not really matter. What is essential is that the displacement is the same for all points, this is what characterises translations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a common shorthand for defining a function. In this case, it is clearly just "translation by $A$", since any $Z$ is mapped to $Z+A$.

Quite often, especially when you don't need to name a function, you just use the "$\mapsto$" notation. An argument in a proof of something could be for instance: "Because the function $x\mapsto x^3$ is continuous."

Sometimes you even don't 'define' the function for arbitrary $x$ and you let the reader think it out. So for example "the exponential that brings $a\mapsto b$" is the same as "the exponential $x\mapsto (b^{1/a})^x$" and the same as "the function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $f(x)=(b^{1/a})^x$".

It is a very convenient notation that avoid too much formalism and too many parentheses.